# Chrome Automation with C/C++ ,PostMessage() can send Message even to a minimized window but it sends extra WM_CHAR message after WM_KEYDOWN message

Tags: c++, winapi, browser-automation, postmessage, sendinput

I am writing a code in C/C++ with Win32API which Automates Chrome(I know there is Selenium and I used that but there is BOT detection available. Just forget about slenium).In my code There are extra features too ie.-If you have multiple Chrome Profile you can chose to run how many Profiles to Run at Once. To change the Tabs in Google Chrome they have the Shortcut Key Ctrl+TAB. I want to Simulate that.

The Problems --->

1.To Run Multiple Profiles at Once.

2.Detecting The Window Handles of Every Profile.

3.Automating Certain Keyboard Events.

I have solved Problem 1 and 2.

Even Problem 3 is easy.To automate Chrome Tab changes I have done something like this ----

```
void clicktabs()
{
    SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
    INPUT ip[4];
    ip[0] = ip[1] = ip[2] = ip[3] = { 0 };
    
    ip[0].type = ip[1].type = ip[2].type = ip[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip[0].ki.wVk = ip[3].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
    
    ip[0].ki.wScan = ip[3].ki.wScan = 0x1D; //scancode of CTRL for my Keyboard
    ip[1].ki.wScan = ip[2].ki.wScan = 0x0F;//scancode of TAB for my Keyboard
    //You can also check for yours by observing the lParam Parameter of WndProc().bit 16 to 23 of lParam is your scan code for that particular key.Though it does not matter.

    ip[3].ki.dwFlags = ip[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    ip[1].ki.wVk = ip[2].ki.wVk = VK_TAB;
    
    for(int count = 1;;count++)
    {
        if (count == //number of tabs you want to open)
        {count = 0;}
            SendInput(4, ip, sizeof(INPUT));
            Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

It is working just fine to press Ctrl+TAB at once.And I am successful to automate TAB changes in Chrome.
Main Problem ---->

SendInput() work on the Focused window. If i change my Focus to other window or if i minimize the window, the chrome TAB change automation stops. To solve it I used PostMessage().Because I have used PostMessage to send mouse clicks on the tabs which it had done succesfully even in minimized window(I dont want to send mouse clicks because after a certain number of tabs the tab size changes.).But postMessage failed to send ctrl+tab message.

I inspect Chrome Window by Spy++ while pressing ctrl+tab by **Myself on My Keyboard**. And it generates-----

1.P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtkey:VK_CONTROL cRepeat: 1 ScanCode:1D fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUP:0

2.P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtkey:VK_TAB cRepeat: 1 ScanCode:0F fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUP:0

3.P WM_KEYUP nVirtkey:VK_TAB cRepeat: 1 ScanCode:0F fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUP:1

4.P WM_KEYUP nVirtkey:VK_CONTROL cRepeat: 1 ScanCode:1D fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUP:1

[Image of messages send by Real Keyboard Input in Spy++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqaiu.jpg)

(Here all the preceeding 'P' means the message is Posted by PostMessage() Note-For normal keydown messages OS PostsMessage not SendMessage().You can see it here - Message Codes -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/message-codes?view=vs-2019)

When I am using SendInput() function and checking browser window with Spy++ it exactly generates the same sequence of Messages as the real keyboard press do.

[Image of messages send by SendInput() in Spy++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyuzE.jpg)

But when I am using PostMessage() like this -

\\\In the below code section i am sure about setting the lParam correctly.Because the values of lParam reflects on  the **cRepeat**, **ScanCode**, **fExtended**, **fAltDown**, **fRepeat**, **fUP** section of Spy++

```
void clicktabs()
{
        SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
        for(int count = 1;;count++)
        {
            if (count == //number of tabs you want to open)
            {count = 0;}
            LPARAM lparam_ctrlkey, lparam_tabkey;
            lparam_ctrlkey = 1 | (1 << 16) | (1 << 18) | (1 << 19) | (1 << 20);
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_CONTROL, lparam_ctrlkey);
            lparam_tabkey = 1| (1 << 16) | (1 << 17) | (1 << 18) | (1 << 19);
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_TAB, lparam_tabkey);
            lparam_tabkey = lparam_tabkey|(1<<30)|(1<<31);  \\stteing up the lparams.
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_TAB, lparam_tabkey);
            lparam_ctrlkey = lparam_ctrlkey | (1 << 30) | (1 << 31);
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_CONTROL, lparam_ctrlkey);
            Sleep(2000);
         }
 }
```

and Checking with Spy++.It generates one extra message(see line 3)-----

1.P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtkey:VK_CONTROL cRepeat: 1 ScanCode:1D fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUP:0

2.P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtkey:VK_TAB cRepeat: 1 ScanCode:0F fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUP:0

3.P WM_CHAR chCharCode:'9' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0F fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0

4.P WM_KEYUP nVirtkey:VK_TAB cRepeat: 1 ScanCode:0F fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUP:1

5.P WM_KEYUP nVirtkey:VK_CONTROL cRepeat: 1 ScanCode:1D fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUP:1

At line 3 it's Generating WM_CHAR for TAB key.ASCII code for TAB key is 0x09 or 9(decimal).And Here PostMessage() fails.

[Image of messages send by PostMessage() in Spy++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmmqW.jpg)

Please help me to solve this.I have seen similar problem on StackOverflow where someone suggested to use SetKeyboardState() . I also tried that but failed.The link is- [Why Am I getting extra messages when sending keystroke to an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554055/why-am-i-getting-extra-messages-when-sending-keystroke-to-an-application)
I also tried SendMessage but it also generates extra WM_KEYDOWN message. You can see it here-[Trouble Simulating Keystrokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982513/trouble-simulating-keystrokes)

[Image of Messages send by SendMessage() in Spy++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEpe4.jpg)

Comment: Stop asking already. [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Comment: Thanks for the link.But There must be any way.Using Assembler or source code of keyboard driver.

Comment: Should i delete the question?

Comment: No there's no workaround - maybe [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview?redirectedfrom=MSDN) (if the client app supports it)

Comment: is there any way redirect SendInput( ) to a specific Window?using hooks or something else?

Comment: `SendInput ` only works on the focused window, how do you want to redirect the focus?

Comment: #Strive Sun - MSFT No way to redirect the focus.Maybe i can manipulate the Message Queue to remove the Char Message out of it.Is there any way to remove a particular message from the Message Queue of a target Window?

Comment: Considering `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook.  Use this hook to intercept `WM_CHAR` message.  [The link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843711/how-do-i-intercept-messages-being-sent-to-a-window) can guide you.